How to click inline button using Telethon?
i have a small problem and hope you'll help me.
i wanted to do small automatization in bot. there is what it shoult do:

go to the chat with bot(no problems here)
send "/start" to bot to get message with inline button(still no problems here)
click on inline button(there is problem)
i used events messages

await client.send_message(bot_username, '/start')
    print('Sent /start to bot')

    # awaiting bot reply
    @client.on(events.NewMessage(from_users=bot_username))
    async def handler(event):
        print('Received message from bot')
        if 'Launch Blum' in event.message.message: #if button found click on it
            await event.message.click(0)
            client.remove_event_handler(handler)

    await client.run_until_disconnected()

i tried remove checking if "Launch Blum" in event, and just click in button. But its not work too.
btw, this button should open web app.
